# Delphi: JPG to Bitmap: Incompatible types: 'TPersistent' and 'TFileName'

Tags: delphi

I'm writing a program that:

1.- Ask the user to select a file, **Any kind of image (JPG, PNG, etc)**
2.- Let's user pixellate the image and shows the new pixellated image.

Since my test image is a JPG, I'm getting error: `Incompatible types: 'TPersistent' and 'TFileName'`

[image]

Before trying to convert the JPG to Bitmap, I was getting:

`Bitmap image is not valid`

[image]

**Code:**

```
unit demo_2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.Imaging.Jpeg;


var
  OpenDialog: TOpenDialog;
  OpenFolder: TFileOpenDialog;
  OriginalImage: TBitmap;
  PixellatedImage: TBitmap;


type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btn1_select_img: TButton;
    btn2_select_output_path: TButton;
    lbl_selected_file: TLabel;
    lbl_output_path: TLabel;
    img1: TImage;
    pnl_img: TPanel;
    pnl_btns: TPanel;
    procedure btn1_select_imgClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btn2_select_output_pathClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btn1_select_imgClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OpenDialog := TOpenDialog.Create(nil);
  OpenDialog.Filter := 'All Files|*.*';
  OpenDialog.Options := [ofPathMustExist, ofFileMustExist];
  try
    if OpenDialog.Execute then
    begin
      // Print the selected file's path to the console
      //WriteLn(OpenDialog.FileName);
      lbl_selected_file.Caption := OpenDialog.FileName;
      img1.Picture.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog.FileName);
    end;
  finally
    //OpenDialog.Free;
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.btn2_select_output_pathClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //OpenFolder := TFileOpenDialog.Create(nil);  for folder selection
  //OpenFolder.Options := [fdoPickFolders];  for folder selection
  try
    //if OpenFolder.Execute then
    begin
      PixellatedImage := TBitmap.Create;
      //PixellatedImage.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog.FileName);
      PixellatedImage.Assign(OpenDialog.FileName);

      // Pixellate the image by setting the Width and Height to a small value
      PixellatedImage.Width := 10;
      PixellatedImage.Height := 10;

      img1.Picture.Bitmap := PixellatedImage;

      //lbl_output_path.Caption := OpenFolder.FileName;   for folder selection
    end;
  finally
    //OpenFolder.Free;
    //OpenDialog.Free;
    PixellatedImage.Free;
  end;

end;

end.
```

Comment: sorry, I thought it was cleared it meant "any image" when I said: ask user to select image, apparently not. Ty for the update.

Answer (score 1):

> Since my test image is a JPG, I'm getting error: Incompatible types: 'TPersistent' and 'TFileName'

Actually, that's wrong in the sense that the error has nothing to do with the image being JPG. So while both "my test image is a JPG" and "I'm getting error ..." are correct, the implication ("since") is not.

The `TPersistent.Assign` method used in

```
PixellatedImage.Assign(OpenDialog.FileName);
```

requires a `TPersistent` object. In this case, when you are dealing with graphics, you typically need a `TGraphic` instance. Hence, you cannot pass a string, even if that string happens to be a file name of an image file.

So if you want to use the `Assign` method on a graphics object, you need to pass it another graphics object -- one you may have loaded from file using its own `LoadFromFile`:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

  var JpegImage := TJPEGImage.Create;
  try

    var OpenDlg := TFileOpenDialog.Create(Self);
    try
      with OpenDlg.FileTypes.Add do
      begin
        DisplayName := 'JPEG images';
        FileMask := '*.jpg';
      end;
      if OpenDlg.Execute then
        JpegImage.LoadFromFile(OpenDlg.FileName)
      else
        Exit;
    finally
      OpenDlg.Free;
    end;

    var BmpImage := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      BmpImage.Assign(JpegImage);
      // For example: BmpImage.SaveToFile('K:\bitmap.bmp');
    finally
      BmpImage.Free;
    end;

  finally
    JpegImage.Free;
  end;

end;
```

---

Also, please note that you must use the idiom

```pascal
LFrog := TFrog.Create;
try
  // use LFrog
finally
  LFrog.Free;
end
```

and never

```pascal
try
  LFrog := TFrog.Create;
  // use LFrog
finally                   // WRONG!
  LFrog.Free;
end
```

assuming `LFrog` is a local variable. If `LFrog` isn't a local variable, it probably should be made local! Otherwise, it is important to do `FreeAndNil` on it and not only `Free`.

---

Update. The Q was changed so it no longer is about JPG -> BMP, but "any" image file to BMP. Then perhaps the best way is to use the Windows Imaging Component:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

  var WicImage := TWICImage.Create;
  try

    var OpenDlg := TFileOpenDialog.Create(Self);
    try
      with OpenDlg.FileTypes.Add do
      begin
        DisplayName := 'All image files';
        FileMask := '*.jpg;*.tiff;*.tif;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp';
      end;
      with OpenDlg.FileTypes.Add do
      begin
        DisplayName := 'JPEG images';
        FileMask := '*.jpg';
      end;
      with OpenDlg.FileTypes.Add do
      begin
        DisplayName := 'TIFF images';
        FileMask := '*.tiff;*.tif';
      end;
      with OpenDlg.FileTypes.Add do
      begin
        DisplayName := 'PNG images';
        FileMask := '*.png';
      end;
      with OpenDlg.FileTypes.Add do
      begin
        DisplayName := 'GIF images';
        FileMask := '*.gif';
      end;
      with OpenDlg.FileTypes.Add do
      begin
        DisplayName := 'Bitmap images';
        FileMask := '*.bmp';
      end;
      // etc.
      if OpenDlg.Execute then
        WicImage.LoadFromFile(OpenDlg.FileName);
    finally
      OpenDlg.Free;
    end;

    var BmpImage := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      BmpImage.Assign(WicImage);
      // For example: BmpImage.SaveToFile('K:\bitmap.bmp');
    finally
      BmpImage.Free;
    end;

  finally
    WicImage.Free;
  end;

end;
```

---

Finally, I note that you write

> ```
> // Pixellate the image by setting the Width and Height to a small value
> PixellatedImage.Width := 10;
> PixellatedImage.Height := 10;
> ```

Although not relevant to your main question about `TGraphic.Assign`, I should note that setting a `TBitmap`'s `Width` and `Height` very much doesn't pixelate the image in the usual sense of the word. (Algorithmically, pixelation should be done like in this [`Pixelate`](https://algosim.org/SynViewSource/ASPixmap.html) procedure.)

Comment: I see. I wannted to about something like: `TJPEGImage.Create;` since image be not be a jpg. Is there a way to do this for any kind of image?

Comment: @OmarGonzales: Perhaps the best way is to use Windows Imaging Component. See `LoadGraphicsFromFile` in https://algosim.org/SynViewSource/ASPixmap.html

Comment: Alternatively, instead of using `TWICImage`, you can use `TPicture` to load the file, and then `Assign()` its `Graphic` property to the `TBitmap`.

Comment: Indeed, @RemyLebeau's suggestion is how it was done before WIC, using only the VCL. If you choose this approach, you must remember to include the appropriate units: `pngimage, GIFImg, jpeg`. No TIFF support.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I completely agree that your comment is very relevant, and I only omitted `TPicture` because I was tired and lazy -- I did feel a bit bad about it. However, I'm curious if you think there is any reason to use `TPicture` instead of `TWICImage` these days? Since `TWICImage` "leverages" on the operating system's graphics capabilities, offers better file format support, makes your binary smaller, doesn't require you to add units explicitly, likely will be kept more up to date in the future, and works since Windows XP, it feels unambiguously superior to me.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand guess I'm just old school. I've never had a need to use WIC myself.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand and Remy, thank you. However, I've been told to about using `with` keyword for Delphi. Not sure why yet. What is your opinion on that? How could this code be done without using `with` keyword?

Comment: @OmarGonzales: Correct. `with` is seldom a good idea, and can cause quite a lot of headache. However, this is a case when it is fairly wise to use `with`. If you still want to avoid `with`: `var FTI := OpenDlg.FileTypes.Add;
      FTI.DisplayName := 'All image files';
      FTI.FileMask := '*.jpg;*.tiff;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp';
      FTI := OpenDlg.FileTypes.Add;
      FTI.DisplayName := 'JPEG images';
      FTI.FileMask := '*.jpg'; // etc`